# Derivation of eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Given a diagonal matrix $D$, we **symmetrize** matrix $W$ by the following transformation: $S \equiv D^{1/2} W D^{-1/2} $

Now, $S$ is a symmetric matrix which is diagonalizable as 
$S = X \Lambda X^T$

The left eigenvectors of $W$ are 
\begin{align}
u_i = x_i D^{1/2}
\end{align}

and the right eigenvectors of $W$ are 
\begin{align}
v_i = x_i D^{-1/2}
\end{align}

I tried $ S = X \Lambda X^T = (D^{1/2}U) \Lambda (VD^{-1/2}) $, because matrices $S$ and $W$ have the same eigenvalues. But I do not get how to derive the expressions for left and right eigenvectors as shown in previous equations. Can someone please explain how that works?

Comment: You shoud write $v_i = D^{-1/2}x_i$. Then (since $X^TX = I$)\begin{align*}Wv_i &= D^{-1/2}SD^{1/2}D^{-1/2}x_i = D^{-1/2}SXe_i = D^{-1/2}X\Lambda X^TXe_i\\ &= D^{-1/2}X\Lambda e_i = \lambda_iD^{-1/2}Xe_i = \lambda_i D^{-1/2}x_i = \lambda_iv_i.\end{align*}

Comment: @amsmath So why do you set $v_i = D^{-1/2} x_i$ straight away at the start and continue?

Comment: I don't get your question. You wrote $v_i = x_iD^{-1/2}$. But this is wrong. If it's the other way around (namely, $v_i = D^{-1/2}x_i$), this is indeed a eigenvector of $W$, as I showed.

Comment: What I mean is that I would like to arrive at the expressions for $u_i$ and $v_i$ from the matrix diagonalization, instead of setting them from the start and showing that they are eigenvectors of the matrix.

Comment: That follows immediately once you notice that the $x_i$ are exactly the eigenvectors of $S$.